# ES6: How to store the object inside this class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The `TopPage_R` class is in certain degree the analogue of [R class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html) in the Android SDK (if don't go into details, the `R` class stores the references to images, string values etc). In my inherited ES6-class, `CSS_CLASSE_SELECTORS` is the static property (actually the method) that returns the css class selector (e. g. `.header`) by class name (e. g. `header`).

```
class R {

    static getSelectorsOfCssClasses(CssClassesObj){

        let OutputCssClassesObj = CssClassesObj;

        for (let key in OutputCssClassesObj){
            OutputCssClassesObj[key] = '.' + CssClassesObj[key];
        }

        return OutputCssClassesObj;
    }
}

class TopPage_R extends R {

    /* required even if constructor in the superclass nas not beed defined */
    constructor() {
        super();
    } 

    static get CSS_CLASSES () { return {
        header: 'header',
        logo: 'logo',
        navmenu: 'navmenu',
        footer: 'footer'
    }}

    static get CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS(){ 
        return R.getSelectorsOfCssClasses(TopPage_R.CSS_CLASSES)}
    }
}
```

Every time we call `CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS` method, new object will be created and
the looping will be executed. What the waste of system resources, in't it?

```
console.log(TopPage_R.CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS.header);
// The new OutputCssClassesObj will be created again
console.log(TopPage_R.CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS.footer);
```

I need the `CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS` stored inside the inherited class.
However I don't want to create the instance of the `TopPage_R`: I want to call
this class and then it's static property as in Android SDK like `setToolbarTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));`

```
let pageResources = new TopPage_R(); // I don't want to create the instance >_<
let $header = jQuery(pageResources.CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS.footer);
```

Can I store the `CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS` inside the `TopPage_R` without creating of it's instance? Assume that `CSS_CLASS` property does not change during web app session.

Comment: You're missing the argument to `R.getSelectorsOfCssClasses()`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `OutputCssClassesObj`? It's not a copy of the argument, so you're modifying the argument object.

Comment: It looks like `R` and `TopPage_R` should be objects, not classes (since you want everything to be static).

Comment: You need to swap the order of the classes, you can't extend `R` before you define it.

Comment: @Barmar `OutputCssClassesObj` has same keys as `CssClassesObj` but different values.

Comment: But you didn't make a copy, so both variables are references to the same object.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu If you `console.log` their values after the loop, you'll see that both objects are the same.

Comment: As for your main question, you need to store the object in the prototype. Then you don't need to create an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, ES6 does not support static properties, only static methods.
But you can use old syntax to set static properties on a class:

```
class TopPage_R extends R {

    ...

    static get CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS() {
        return R.getSelectorsOfCssClasses(TopPage_R.CSS_CLASSES);
    }
}

TopPage_R.CSS_CLASSES = {
    header: 'header',
    logo: 'logo',
    navmenu: 'navmenu',
    footer: 'footer'
};
```

Another option, will be to define your css classes as a variable outside of the class. If you are using ES6 modules, then this variable will be hidden from the rest of your app, so no worries about privacy.

```
let CSS_CLASSES = {
    header: 'header',
    logo: 'logo',
    navmenu: 'navmenu',
    footer: 'footer'
};

class TopPage_R extends R {

    static get CSS_CLASSES () {
        return CSS_CLASSES;
    }

    static get CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS() {
        return R.getSelectorsOfCssClasses(TopPage_R.CSS_CLASSES);
    }
}
```

Or you can use Babel with [Class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to compile you code and then use:

```
class TopPage_R extends R {

    static CSS_CLASSES = {
        header: 'header',
        logo: 'logo',
        navmenu: 'navmenu',
        footer: 'footer'
    };

    static get CSS_CLASS_SELECTORS() {
        return R.getSelectorsOfCssClasses(TopPage_R.CSS_CLASSES);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I knew that ES2015 does not support declarations like `static someProp = 'test';` , but is the `static get someProp() { return 'test'; }` is the imitation of static property?

Comment: Yes, it is. In your case it is a static "getter" method, which is a static property. The problem, as you suggested, is that if you will return non scalar value, for example an object. Then it will create that object every time you use the property (or call the "getter" method). So the solution is to return a reference to the object that is stored in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this works with it being static specifically, but if you want to make a method available to a Class or Object without it running on every new instance you need to add it to the prototype.

```
R.prototype.getSelectorsOfCssClasses = function(CssClassesObj) {
  ...
}
```

See this question for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837860/1763258

> Consider a classroom full of students. Putting something on the prototype is like putting something on the white board for them all to see.